# Extend log4j error emails with more information

Tags: java, logging, log4j

The web application on which I am working procvides more logs for data integrity issues of the users. I would like to get some more information like:

- servername
- client ip
- browser info

Is there a way with log4j to be able to log above parameters? In other words, I would like to add these parameters with other parameters. So do log4j provides some method for this ?

I have log4j.properties as :

```
log4j.appender.Stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%-5p - %-26.26c{1} - %m\n

log4j.appender.Stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%-5p - %-26.26c{1} - %m\n

log4j.rootLogger=INFO,Stdout

log4j.logger.org.apache.wicket=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.HttpSessionStore=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.wicket.version=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle=INFO
```

I have a `LogUtil.java` class in which I am logging the availiable info.

**EDIT:**
To be more clear what my question is:

Where to find these parameter and how to add them in the existing logger ?

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know where to find that information, Or how to add it automatically to existing log statements?

Comment: Is not `Logger#info(...)` acceptable?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen : Yes, Exactly where to find that information and what method should be used for it. I will update the question.

Comment: It is available in the parameters passed into the servlet.  Just get it from there.  If you are using a framework which provides a servlet for you , you need to ask the framework.

Answer (score 3):

These info can be get from HttpServletRequest object.
You can use MDC to accomplish this.

[Log4j MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) Tutorial](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/)

You can customize also customize the details sent in the Log4j email  by extending [SMTPAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html)

Check this blog , this should give you how to

[Customize SMTPAppender](http://weblog.plexobject.com/?p=1673)

Answer (score 3):

Look into MDC.

You should setup the MDC with information you mentioned before actually start your processing.  Then you can include such information in the log message.

Answer (score 1):

Check the HttpServletRequest class api which provides most of the information you need. Lot of information will be available via the request headers.

Where ever you are doing logging in your java code you can create a logging string using above values.

The other option is using MDC where if you set things then it will be logged automatically.